# To move SQL Server Agent Jobs from one server to another

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-agent

I just need some advise or solution please.

I have SQL Server `SQL1` and it has more than 50 agent jobs. I have to move those jobs to a new SQL Server called `SQL2`.

What is the best, easiest and most secure way to do so? Is there any copy and paste way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: script out the jobs.....

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/move-sql-databases-to-a-different-server-using-sql-server-log-shipping/

step by step explained here

Comment: [How to move a SQL Agent Job to another Server?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/55278/how-to-move-a-sql-agent-job-to-another-server)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

2 ways that I know of:

1. [Generate Scripts for SQL Server Objects](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/2205291/Generate-Scripts-for-SQL-Server-Objects.htm)
2. [Scripting all Agent Jobs Using SQL Server Management Studio](https://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Scripting%20all%20Agent%20Jobs%20Using%20SQL%20Server%20Management%20Studio%20(SSMS).aspx)

Comment: link only answers are frowned upon on SO

Answer (score 1):

you can use management studio, right click on specified job

> Script Job as > Create to > ....

Answer (score 0):

Use SSIS component called "Transfer Job Task" which you can find in other tasks

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).